# Add a property to JSON Object obtained from remote data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

I have an array of JSON objects that I obtained like this

```
var arr = [];

$.getJSON( 'http://localhost:port/api/blah/blah', function( jsonPayload ) {

      console.log('Getting JSON...');

      // Do stuff with JSON data here, or call a function here and
      // pass the data to it as an argument

      arr = jsonPayload;
      console.log('arr IS SET!');
      functionCall();
      //printArr(arr);
});
```

Which my array, arr, has a bunch of JSON objects that look like this

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "Joe Schmo",
  "blah": "blah",
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Anddd I try to add a new property to **Each** of these objects like so

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.lenth ; i++)
{
    var curr = arr[i];
    curr.newProp= 0;
}//end for loop adding newProp property
```

Yet when I look over the finished array with the JSON objects I find out that My newProp **wasn't** added to the JSON objects.

Why is this and can you help me out?

Comment: BTW: Why you define `curr`? it is not used in your code

Comment: edit: That was a typo when I posted the question, i fixed now. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: You have lenth instead of length

Comment: Yeah, try `console.log(arr.length)` before starting your for loop. arr might be overwritten by the ajax after your loop is executed.

Comment: @juvian THAT WAS IT! A GOD DAMN TYPO! Welp I feel dumb :/ +1 Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var test = [{a:1},{b:2}];
test.forEach(function(obj) { obj["newProp"] = 0;});
```

Comment: How using `forEach` instead of the `for` loop makes a difference?

Comment: @Lost1 I didn't get.

Comment: @vikas Its no longer downvoted...

Comment: Some explanation on how this answers the question would help greatly

Comment: It reduces the amount of words that might cause a spelling error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.lenth ; i++)
```

use

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++)
```

whenever something does not work and it should work, typo is a possible cause.